# How to write tag in my spring project?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I want to write my tag (extends `TagSupport`) in my spring framework. In my tag class, will use some service which should auto inject by spring. But I always get null, seems spring can't inject service instance in my tag class.

The code is like the following:

```
public class FetchTagNameTag extends TagSupport {

   @Autowired
   private TaskService taskService;
   ...
```

`taskService` is always null.

How can I resolve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSP tag objects are not managed by Spring, they are managed by the servlet container. As a result, you cannot autowire stuff into your tags.

If you need to get hold of beans from the spring appcontext, then your Spring MVC controller needs to set the bean as a request attribute (using `request.setAttribute()`), so that the tag object can get hold of it.

Answer (score 16):

Have a try by utilizing `RequestContextAwareTag`. It will offer you methods to obtain RequestContext and then WebApplicaitonContext. Have a look at [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/index.html?org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/RequestContextAwareTag.html).

Comment: this is so simple and just works. I don't know why the answer for using MVC controller to autowire is voted.

Comment: Not only is this simple and works - it's the better answer.  The other answer involving the controller setting a request attribute requires documentation in the taglib and extra code by anyone that uses this taglib on pages that don't use the same controller.  It also has side effects of not working should someone forget to set the request attribute on a new, unrelated page.

Comment: `getRequestContext().getWebApplicationContext().getBean(MyBean.class)`. Finally!!

Answer (score 1):

Annotate your Tag-Implementation with `@Configurable` and add `<context:component-scan base-package="your.webapp">` to your Spring-Configuration.

Comment: Sorry,your approach does not work for me. Are you sure about this method?

Answer (score 0):

Check out these spring packages in the spring reference docs and in the spring source:

org.springframework.web.servlet.tags

org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form

If nothing else, those will show you how the spring developers wrote the spring tags.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create a static method like this:

```
public static void autowireAllFor(Object target) {
    AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor bpp = new AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
    bpp.setBeanFactory(...yourBeanFactory...);
    bpp.processInjection(target);
}
```

and then for your tag you could do

```
public class YourTag extends TagSupport {

   @Autowired
   private SomeBean someBean;

   public YourTag() {
      YourHelperClass.autowireAllFor(this);
   }
}
```

The obvious disadvantage of this approach is that you have to do this for every constructor, but as `TagSupport` only has one, it should not be a problem. You can go even one step further and create a helper superclass which always guarantees autowiring:

```
public class SpringTagSupport extends TagSupport {
   public SpringTagSupport() {
      super();
      YourHelperClass.autowireAllFor(this);
   }
}
```

The rest is as easy as extending your classes from `SpringTagSupport`.

Comment: Doesn't matter - just keep it in a some utility class. In this example it is pictured being inside `YourHelperClass`.

Answer (score 0):

First I write this:

```
public abstract class SpringSuportedTag  extends SimpleTagSupport{

protected WebApplicationContext _applicationContext;

protected WebApplicationContext getSpringContext(){
    PageContext pageContext = (PageContext) getJspContext();
    if(_applicationContext==null){
        _applicationContext = RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(
                pageContext.getRequest(),
                pageContext.getServletContext()
            );
        initCustomBeans();
    }
    return _applicationContext;
}

protected abstract void initCustomBeans();

/**
 * Deprecated for inserting extra logic. Use {@link #doTagWithSpring()} instead.
 */
@Override
@Deprecated
public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {
    getSpringContext();
    doTagWithSpring();
}


abstract void doTagWithSpring() throws JspException, IOException;
}
```

And usage:

```
public class SlotTag extends SpringSuportedTag {

//  @Resource(name="userDetailHolder")
//  not work here
UserDetailHolder userDetail;

private String slotname;

public String getSlotname() {
    return slotname;
}

public void setSlotname(String slotname) {
    this.slotname = slotname;
}

@Override
void doTagWithSpring() throws JspException, IOException {
    PageContext pageContext = (PageContext) getJspContext();
    String userDetailCode = pageContext.getAttribute(InitWidgetUserTag.KAY_USERDETAIL,  PageContext.PAGE_SCOPE).toString();
    userDetail.init(userDetailCode);
    String pageID = pageContext.getAttribute(InitWidgetUserTag.KAY_PAGEID,  PageContext.PAGE_SCOPE).toString();

    getJspContext().getOut().println("<b>slot for user:"+userDetail.getUserId()+"</b>");
}

@Override
protected void initCustomBeans() {
    userDetail = (UserDetailHolder) getSpringContext().getBean("userDetailHolder");

}
}
```

It's work.
**But than** i found this:
[Spring supported Tag Libraries](http://www.shredzone.org/projects/jshred/wiki/Spring_supported_Tag_Libraries). Truth in my progect I still use own solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use :-

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag;

public class FetchTagNameTag extends RequestContextAwareTag {

//   @Autowired

  // private TaskService taskService;

   @Override

    protected int doStartTagInternal() throws Exception {

TaskService taskService=  getRequestContext().getWebApplicationContext().getBean(TaskService.class);


    return 0;
   }
```