# Inject dependency into a taglib class?

Tags: java, spring, taglib

I'm using Spring 3 and want to inject some dependencies into a class that is part of a taglib. I can imagine some kludge using constructor-arg, but I'm hoping someone else has a better idea.

Comment: "Don't do it" would be my advice.

Comment: Why not? I want my tag to load data from a service.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924909/how-to-write-tag-in-my-spring-project

Comment: The below answer worked, but another option I discovered that suited me well enough was to put static property on the tag class and inject it using MethodInvokingFactoryBean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should you decide to access a Service or DAO from a custom tag then you need to access the ApplicationContext from the tag and then get the Bean.

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(pageContext.getServletContext()); 
MyService myService = applicationContext.getBean(MyService.class);
myService.doSomething();
```

Comment: pageContext is a protected attribute in TagSupport

Answer (score 1):

There is also http://www.shredzone.org/projects/jshred/wiki/Spring_supported_Tag_Libraries - this works by creating a proxy class for each taglib class handles the interaction with Spring, and uses Spring to generate an instance of the taglib when required.