# Get config setting in custom taglib using Spring "context-property-placeholder"

Tags: spring, taglib

I'm creating a custom taglib, and would like to use some config options that are loaded via the underlying Spring framework using:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties" />
```

How would I get access to these variables in my taglib?

Thanks,

James.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSP taglibs have nothing in common with the Spring context's lifecycle, they're managed by the servlet container. This can complicate things a bit, for example: [inject-dependency-into-a-taglib-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389773/inject-dependency-into-a-taglib-class), [how-to-write-tag-in-my-spring-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924909/how-to-write-tag-in-my-spring-project).

Since you're only mentioning the need for contents of the properties file, you could use plain old `java.util.ResourceBundle` (or, if you need more flexibility, Apache Commons' `org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration`).

*(One could also argue that requiring access to configuration in your tags indicates a design problem...)*