# Use Spring Message Tag in Attributes - The best way?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, taglib

It's not a possible to use a tag in an attribute:

```
<input type="submit" value="<sp:message code="send" />" />
```

There's no way to use this message tag as a function:

```
<input type="submit" value="${sp:message('send')}" />
```

The only way is to save the message in a var ([as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273958/how-to-use-springmessage-inside-an-attribute-of-forminput)), but I think using a function would be much better than this:

```
<sp:message code="send" var="tmp_send" />
<input type="submit" value="${tmp_send}" />
```

So I would like to write my own function:

```
<taglib xmlns...>
    <function>
        <description>Be able to use Spring messages in attribute values</description>
        <name>message</name>
        <function-class>com.example.MyTagLib</function-class>
        <function-signature>String message(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
</taglib>
```

But there's a design problem accessing MessageSource here ([as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856097/get-config-setting-in-custom-taglib-using-spring-context-property-placeholder)).

```
public class MyTagLib {
    public static String message(String code) {
        // TODO: use messageSource to resolve message
        return code;
    }
}
```

Isn't there a better way to acess spring messages in attributes?