# Spring and auto-wiring: NullPointerException

Tags: spring, autowired

I'm trying to get a grip on auto-wiring in Spring, but I can't seem to properly instantiate the bean (a `DocumentBuilder`).  I have created a custom JSP tag as such:

```
public class MyTag extends SimpleTagSupport {

    @Autowired
    private DocumentBuilder documentBuilder;

    public void setBuilder(DocumentBuilder builder) {
        this.documentBuilder = builder;
    }

    @Override
    public void doTag() throws IOException {
        // documentBuilder is null in here!
    }
}
```

This is the servlet configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Scan for HTTP/REST controllers -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="the.right.package" />

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="documentBuilderFactory"
          class="javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory"
          factory-method="newInstance">
        <property name="validating" value="false" />
        <property name="ignoringElementContentWhitespace" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="documentBuilder" class="javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder"
          factory-bean="documentBuilderFactory"
          factory-method="newDocumentBuilder">
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure the tags are being that easily injected with dependencies - shouldn't You do:
    ApplicationContext context = getContext();
    documentBuilder = context.getBean("documentBuilder");

instead ?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. I'm completely new to Spring and DI!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write tag in my spring project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924909/how-to-write-tag-in-my-spring-project)

Comment: looks like I am right - the Tags are not managed by Spring - so You can't inject dependencies automatically then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only inject in spring beans! But Jsp-Tags are no Spring Beans, so the Autowird annotation will be completely ignored, and therefore the field is null.

There are two solution:

- use the `@Configurable` Support. -- But that requires real AspectJ. (I have never tried it for Tags, but I guess it will work for tags like for every other normal class). @see [Spring Reference: Chapter 7.8.1 Using AspectJ to dependency inject domain objects with Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable)
- Extend your tag from the abstract Spring class [`RequestContextAwareTag`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/RequestContextAwareTag.html). This provides access to the `WebApplicationContext` via `getRequestContext().getWebApplicationContext()`. Then you can use the `WebApplicationContext` to obtain the required beans programmatic.

Comment: This is a viable solution. I've used `@Configurable` to successfully autowire stuff in non-Spring-managed objects lots of times.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the code like this

```
public class MyTag extends SimpleTagSupport {

    private DocumentBuilder documentBuilder;

    @Autowired
    public void setBuilder(DocumentBuilder builder) {
        this.documentBuilder = builder;
    }

    @Override
    public void doTag() throws IOException {
        // documentBuilder is null in here!
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a good idea to explain what you changed and why you think such a change should be made.

Comment: Just changed wiring to setter method, because it could change documentBuilder field with incorrect null value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Autowired if you mark your tag class as Spring bean. But it's stupid, because simple tags not caching by container. Each request creates own tag instance, but wiring happend only conteiner starts.